# Hide web part zone containing two repeaters if no child pages exist

Tags: kentico

I have a Web part zone that have two repeaters. Each repeater uses the same Path '/Processes/%'. What is the best way to hide the entire web part zone if no child pages exist in '/Processes/%' ?

The pages I am checking for do not live directly under the page but under a child page. How do I check for grandchild pages under a specific path ? '/Processes/%' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Documents` macro to access the correct document, and check if it has children.

If the alias path of your `Processes` page is `/Processes`, and you want to check if it has child pages (`/Processes/%`):

```
{% Documents["/Processes"].NodeHasChildren %}
```

If the alias path is `/MyPage/Processes` (and the children being under `/MyPage/Processes/%`):

```
{% Documents["/MyPage/Processes"].NodeHasChildren %}
```

You can then use that as a macro on the "Visible" property of your WebPart Zone.

Comment: Great suggestion. Would it be necessary to add ["./Processes"] so the path could be more dynamic ?

Answer (score 1):

Enter a macro into web part zone visibility property:

```
{%CurrentDocument.NodeHasChildren%}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm actually checking for "Grandchild" pages. The Page has a "folder" that contains the actual pages I'm looking for. So MyPage/Processes/ChildPage - Need to check for these grandchild pages

Answer (score 1):

The Repeater has the Hide if no record found property that hides it automatically, but if you really need look for chrandchildren you would have to go through all child pages in a loop:

```
{%
result = false;
foreach (p IN CurrentDocument.Children) {
 if (p.NodeHasChildren) {
  return true;
 }
}
return result;
%}
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps. The only thing I would change would be to add a break once it found a child.

Comment: return breaks the function, so it stops processing when it finds a child